# Swift: possible reasons for why IBOutlets have stopped working?

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to set IB Outlets to text I get the error Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file. Why is this? I have seen similar questions but none of the solutions work for me. I have many swift files that I am passing data through so tell me if you have a question about those.

to pass the data- i did

```
var currentViewControllerIndex = vcthing?.getCurrentIndex()
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TownSelectedViewController") as? TownSelectedViewController
        //currentViewControllerIndex =
        vc?.passerStr = selectedValues[currentViewControllerIndex!]
```

and the problem occurs when I do this

```
vc?.loopTownsForPopulation
```

The function loopTownsForPopulation in Town SelectedViewController tries to set passerStr to a label and although passerStr is set to the right value and I am able to print it and i can assign the label in THE VIEW DID LOAD, the Label doesn't work in another function and instead says Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file.

Comment: your connection breaks in storyboard ...

Comment: 1. Check your connections in storyboard. 2. How are you creating the view controller instance? - Did it come via a segue?  3. Are you trying to set an Outlet in `prepare(for segue:)`?

Comment: I did this                guard let pageViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: String(describing: CustomPageViewController.self)) as? CustomPageViewController else {
            return
        }.  and then I get that error on this contentView.addSubview(pageViewController.view)

Comment: Please edit your question to show that code. Do you do anything else between creating the VC and adding its view?

Comment: I revised, do you need more?

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't have anything to do with outlet connections

Answer (score 1):

Example with textField :

- Your IB Outlets lost connection with your storyboards ( textField
  still in storyboard).
- Your IB Outlets is removed / change name in your ViewController but still exist in your Storyboard.
- You copy your item in your ViewController to another one. It may keeps the references and may crash

Comment: How could I have coped my item in my ViewController to another one.

Comment: You can copy your item / viewController in storyboard and parse to another ViewController / storyboard

Comment: I'm not understanding this sorry, can you give me an example on how I could fix this

Comment: Try delete the label in your storyboard and create a new one connect it to your ViewController

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: Can you upload your project on github ?